# Scala: How to combine methods that return a Future

Tags: scala, future

Given a `Map` that stores exchange rates from EUR/USD to BTC...

```
val btcRates = Map("EUR" -> 0.0036, "USD" -> 0.0045)
```

... and the following two methods...

```
// returns a Future containing a Map of value to convert to BTC
def getAmounts = Future(Map("EUR" -> 500.0, "USD" -> 550.0, "CHF" -> 400))

// returns a Future containing the exchange rate for the specified currency
def getBtcRate(refCurrency: String) = Future(btcRates(refCurrency))
```

How do I invoke `getAmounts` and then for each element of the `Map` it returns invoke `getBtcRate` to convert the amount to BTC? And how do I sum all the converted amounts?

```
def getTotal: Future[Double] = {
  getAmounts.flatMap { _.map { case (currency, amount) =>
    getBtcRate(currency).flatMap { rate =>
      amount * rate // how do I sum this and how do I return the result?
    }
  }}
}
```

Comment: What is `rates` and `refCurrency`?

Comment: Yes... sorry, they were two typos... just fixed.

Comment: I would add the expected output to this with your sample data. Also, I'm not sure I'd put a `Map` in a `Future` for `getAmounts`. This doesn't seem to fit the spirit of a `Future` which is a "a placeholder object that you can create for a result that does not yet exist".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used *for-comprehension* for `getTotal` since it's a little easier on the eyes than a chain of `flatmap`s:

```
  def getTotal: Future[Double] = for {
    amounts <- getAmounts
    totals <- Future.sequence(
      amounts.map { case (currency, amount) => 
        getBtcRate(currency).map(rate => amount * rate)
      }
    )
  } yield totals.sum
```

What this does is that `amounts` is the result of `getAmounts` (really this is the body of your `flatmap`). You then map over that tuple to create a sequence of futures by calling `getBtcRate` for each `currency`. Each of those futures is then mapped to get the total.

Now you have a `Iterable[Future[Double]]` and using `Future.sequence` you transform it into a `Future[Iterable[Double]]`

Now you can just yield that `Iterable` and `sum` it, yielding the desired `Future[Double]`.

Comment: Thank you very much... I was missing the  `Future.sequence` stuff ;-)